# json dumps escape characters

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I'm having some trouble with escape characters and json.dumps.

It seems like extra escape characters are being added whenever json.dumps is called.  Example:

```
not_encoded = {'data': '''!"#$%'()*+,-/:;=?@[\]^_`{|}~0000&<>'''}
print(not_encoded)
{'data': '!"#$%\'()*+,-/:;=?@[\\]^_`{|}~0000&<>'}
```

This is fine, but when I do a json dumps it adds a lot of extra values.

```
json.dumps(not_encoded)
'{"data": "!\\"#$%\'()*+,-/:;=?@[\\\\]^_`{|}~0000&<>"}'
```

The dump shouldn't look like this.  It's double escaping the \ and the ".  Anyone know why this is and how to fix it?  I would want the json.dumps to output

```
'{"data": "!\"#$%'()*+,-/:;=?@[\\]^_`{|}~0000&<>"}'
```

*edit*

Loading back in the dump:

```
the_dump = json.dumps(not_encoded)
json.loads(the_dump)
{u'data': u'!"#$%\'()*+,-/:;=?@[\\]^_`{|}~0000&<>'}
```

The problem is I'm hitting an API endpoint which needs these special characters, but it goes over character limit when the json.dumps adds additional escape characters (`\\\\` and `\\"`).

Comment: why it "shouldn't"? What do you get when you `loads` is back?

Comment: See my edit above ^

Comment: It would have been better if you made `not_encoded = {'data': '"'}`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is worth reading up on the difference between `print`, `str` and `repr` in python (see [here for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)). You are comparing the printed original string with a repr of the json encoding, the latter will have double escapes - one from the json encoding and one from python's string representation.

But otherwise there is no issue, if you compare `len(not_encoded['data'])` with `len(json.loads(json.dumps(not_encoded))['data'])` you will find they are the same. There are no extra characters, but there are different methods of displaying them.

Comment: I think the OP's issue is that the *JSON encoded data grows*, and as far as I can tell, this is impossible to prevent?

Comment: I thought he was concerned about json.dumps 'double escaping the \ and "'. The second escape was from the call to repr, not the json encoding (as you point out it is required to escape those two special characters)

Comment: Ah, I see your point now. Perhaps that *is* what the question is about, but in that case it shouldn't affect what is actually sent over the wire.

Answer (score 4):

`json.dumps` is *required* to escape `"` and `\` according to the [JSON standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf). If the API uses JSON you cannot avoid your data to grow in length when using these characters.

From [json.org](http://json.org/):

[image: JSON string syntax]